# rangFloat for odd numbers

Tags: python

```
for i in range(1, 10, 2):#use (start,end,step)
    print(i)
```

this program prints out odd numbers from 1-10.

However if I want to jump half a unit at a time (e.g. 1, 1.5, 2, …), you cannot use `range(1,10,0.5)`.

- Can anyone tell me a  method range Float that solves the problem.

Comment: Why to use a range function ? you can easily use a while loop instead ?